# react-native-countdown - get onchange tick value

Tags: react-native

I was able to implement the `react-native-countdown-component` successfully, but tried getting the value of the countdown-timer as it ticks from the `onChange` which i couldent get.

**FIND MY CODE BELLOW**

```
<CountDown
    until={60 * this.state.assessmentDurationMain + 2}
    size={20}
    onChange={(time)=>{

        console.warn(time)
        //AsyncStorage.setItem('startTest_'+this.state.assessmentID,time)
    }}
    onFinish={() => alert('Finished')}
    digitStyle={{backgroundColor: '#f2f2f1'}}
    digitTxtStyle={{color: '#80146D'}}
    timeToShow={['H','M', 'S']}
    timeLabels={{h:'HR',m: 'MM', s: 'SS'}}
/>
```

the function on the `onChange` returns null on the `console.warn(time)` output
.

So my question is, how can i return the time value as it ticks using the `react-native-countdown-component` package ?

Comment: [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component/v/1.8.2) package does not have **onChange** prop.

Comment: It has an onChange props..

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the source code [talalmajali/react-native-countdown](https://github.com/talalmajali/react-native-countdown-component/blob/master/index.js#L104-L114), you'll notice that it simply calls your callback...

```
if (this.props.onChange) {
  this.props.onChange();
}
```

So if you need the time to be passed back, you could fork the repo and updated as so (in both places it's called)...

```
if (this.props.onChange) {
  this.props.onChange(this.state.until);
}
```

Comment: First i was oubting this openion untill i tried it out.
You seem to be very correct.
My timer has a time of `7:00` mins but i get an integer value of 400+.. which i believe should be a time equivalent.

Comment: Adding to what you said, i was able to get the exact time equivalent by adding the function ``getTimeLeft`...

  getTimeLeft = () => {
     const {until} = this.state;
     return {
       seconds: until % 60,
       minutes: parseInt(until / 60, 10) % 60,
       hours: parseInt(until / (60 * 60), 10) % 24,
       days: parseInt(until / (60 * 60 * 24), 10),
      };
    };

Comment: clever! I was trying to figure out how to extract the value from the callback itself, but it wasn't coming to me :). Great job!